# Updating State Breaks Child Prop Component

Tags: reactjs

I am still trying to get a handle on parent-child data sharing and have an issue where my stateful component has an array of objects that display correctly within my child prop components via `componentWillReceiveProps()`, but when I trigger my `updateCommentsFunc()` function, which is triggered by a child component form, the POST is called and value is appended to the array, but I get an `undefined` error from my child component that demonstrates that the data isn't flowing post state update.

Am I using the wrong method? Should I add something to my `updateCommentsFunc()`?

**Here is the console error:**

```
    Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'picture' of undefined
        at Comment (comment.js?2fa6:15)
        at mountIndeterminateComponent (react-dom.development.js?cada:10400)
        at beginWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:10601)
        at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:12573)
        at workLoop (react-dom.development.js?cada:12682)
        at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js?cada:1299)
        at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js?cada:1338)
        at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js?cada:1195)
        at performWork (react-dom.development.js?cada:12800)
        at scheduleUpdateImpl (react-dom.development.js?cada:13185)
```

**Triggered at line:**

```
    <img src={props.user.picture} className="comment__record-profile"/>
```

**This is the parent component which is fed an object that has its nested array mapped and stored in an array in the state:**

```
    //Loop through JSON and create Comment and Comment Container Component
    class CommentFeed extends React.Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props);
            this.state = { 
                comments: []
            };
            this.updateCommentsFunc = this.updateCommentsFunc.bind(this);
        }

        //Load Array to component
        componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
            let commentArr = [];
            nextProps.comments.map((comment) => {
                comment.comment_comments.map((comment) => {
                    commentArr.push(comment);
                })
            })
            this.setState({comments: commentArr});
        }

        //Append new POST value to commentArr
        updateCommentsFunc(newComments){
            var updatedCommentArr = this.state.comments.slice();
            updatedCommentArr.push(newComments)
            this.setState({comments: updatedCommentArr});
        }

        render(){
            return (
                <div>
                { 
                    this.props.comments.map((comment, index) => {
                        return (
                            <div className="row">
                                <div className="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 comment-card">
                                    <CommentCard {...comment} key={comment.commentIdHash} user={this.props.user} />
                                    <Comments comments={this.state.comments} key={index} commentId={comment.commentIdHash} csrf={this.props.csrf} updateComments={this.updateCommentsFunc}/> 
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        );
                    })
                }
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

**Here is the child component split into a form and displayed comments:**

```
    //Blog Comment - Container
    export default class Comments extends React.Component {
        render() {
            return (
                <div className="blog-comment-container">
                    <CommentForm updateComments={this.props.updateComments} blogId={this.props.blogId} csrf={this.props.csrf}/>
                    { this.props.comments.map((comment, i) =>
                        <AttachedComment commentObj={comment} blogComponentId={this.props.blogId}/>
                        )}

                </div>
            );
        }
    }
```

**Here is the form calling `this.props.updateComments()` with the returned JSON data from the POST:**

```
class CommentForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            value: ''
        };

        this.postComment = this.postComment.bind(this);
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    }

    postComment(comment, blogId, csrfToken) {
        var body = { comment: comment };
        var route = 'http://localhost:3000/app/blog/' + blogId + '/comment';
        fetch(route, 
            { 
                method: 'POST', 
                body: JSON.stringify(body), 
                headers: { 
                    'X-CSRF-Token': csrfToken,
                    'Accept': 'application/json',
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            })
            .then(res => {
                return res.json();
            })  
            .then(data => {
                this.props.updateComments(data)
            }) 
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err);
            });
    }

    onChange(e){
        this.setState({
            value: e.target.value
        });
    }

    handleSubmit(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        this.postComment(this.state.value, this.props.blogId, this.props.csrf);
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="blog-comment__form">
                <div className="row">
                    <div className="col-md-12">
                        <label>Comment:</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                        <form action={"/app/blog/" + this.props.blogId + "/comment"} method="post" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                            <input type="hidden" name="_csrf" value={this.props.csrf}/>
                            <div className="col-md-9">
                                <textarea name="comment" className="blog-comment__form-text-area" onChange={e => this.setState({ value: e.target.value })} value={this.state.value}></textarea>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-3">
                                <button type="submit" className="blog-comment__form-button" disabled={!this.state.value}>Comment</button>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

**Here is the conditional that checks to see if the nested array Id matches the id from the fed object at the parent:**

```
const AttachedComment = props => {
    if(props.commentObj.blogIdHash == props.blogComponentId){
        return (
            <Comment {...props.commentObj} key={props.commentObj.blogCommentId}/>
            )
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Finally, if that returns `TRUE` then the component where the error appeared is rendered:**

```
const Comment = props => {
    return (
        <div className="comment-comment__record">
            <div className="row">
                <div className="col-md-12">
                    <div className="comment-comment__meta">
                        <div className="row">
                            <div className="col-md-6">
                                <img src={props.user.picture} className="comment-comment__record-profile"/>
                            </div>
                            <div className="col-md-6">

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <h5>{props.user_id}</h5>
                    <h4>{props.comment}</h4>
                    <h3>{props.synotate_user.fullNameSlug}</h3>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: `props.commentObj` seems to not contain the object `user`, make sure its available

Comment: You are correct! I forgot that my post won't contain the nested `user` object since this isn't a query containing the table joins. I will have to update my controlled to include a query post comment creation and nest that information within the returned JSON that is being used in the array update